# Polymer layout toolbar + core-drawer-panel

Tags: css, layout, polymer

Before continue reading:
This is a **polymer 0.5** question and has been deprecated after 1.0 release.

I'm trying to have a toolbar always shown at the top of the web. Then, split the container in a core-drawer-panel, but this element is being displayed always at the top of the web, overwriting the toolbar.

Using the polymer designer: I want to achieve something like this:

[image: desired layout]

If I get the code from the designer, I have:

```
    <core-toolbar id="core_toolbar"></core-toolbar>
    <core-drawer-panel transition id="core_drawer_panel" touch-action>
      <section id="section" drawer></section>
      <section id="section1" main>
        <core-field id="core_field" icon="search" theme="core-light-theme" center horizontal layout>
          <core-input id="core_input" flex></core-input>
        </core-field>
      </section>
    </core-drawer-panel>
```

But if I just use that code, the core-drawer goes to top, hiding the toolbar, resulting in something like:

[image: bad layout]

Any idea about how to "move" the core-drawer-panel if there's a toolbar?

Keep in mind **I don't want to have a toolbar in the drawer** [as in the example](https://www.polymer-project.org/samples/layout-elements/drawer-app.vulcanized.html), but one for the whole app.
Of course, I know I could achieve it by using CSS, but I'm wondering if I'm setting wrong the polymer elements structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `core-header-panel` in order to host your `core-toolbar` and `core-drawer-panel`. It will prevent `core-drawer-panel` of overlapping `core-toolbar` as you pictured in your example. Here is a jsfiddle and snipped:

http://jsfiddle.net/kreide/ehwa3w1n/

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
core-header-panel {
  height: 100%;
}
[drawer] {
    box-shadow: 1px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

[main] {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(231, 238, 238);
}
```

```html
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/paper-elements.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-elements/core-elements.html">

<body fullbleed layout vertical>
    <core-header-panel flex>
        <core-toolbar>
          <div>Hello World!</div>
        </core-toolbar>
        <div class="content">
            <core-drawer-panel>
                <section drawer>Left</section>
                <section main>Right</section>
            </core-drawer-panel>
        </div>
    </core-header-panel>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution by kreide doesn't work for Polymer 1.0

To affix paper-drawer-panel in 1.0 add a css style = "position:relative" to the drawer tag.

Comment: @MarioLevrero I was talking about the 1.0 counterpart